# Get external html page onclick content with php

Tags: php, html

Ok lets say i have an html file like this . . .

```
<div class="vad buttonDiv" onclick="location.href='http://example.htm?some/link&id=1357900324528'">
<div class="vad buttonDiv" onclick="other('example')">
<div class="vad buttonDiv" onclick="location.href='http://example.htm?some/link&id=7458758375733'">
<div class="vad buttonDiv" onclick="other('example1')">
<div class="vad buttonDiv" onclick="location.href='http://example.htm?some/link&id=3474537737392'">
<div class="vad buttonDiv" onclick="other('example2')">
```

what i want to do is for each `http://example.htm?some/link&id=**************` i want to display just them from the external html page i tried the code below

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$onclicks = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//div");

for ($i = 0; $i < $onclicks->length; $i++) {
    $onclick = $onclicks->item($i);
    $display = $onclick->getAttribute("onclick");
    echo $display."<br>";
}
```

and it gets this

```
location.href='http://example.htm?some/link&id=1357900324528'
other('example')

location.href='http://example.htm?some/link&id=7458758375733
other('example1')

location.href='http://example.htm?some/link&id=3474537737392
other('example2')
```

any idea's how to get just what i am after and not both on click content any answers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not familiar with XPath, so not sure, but can you use something like `"/html/body//div[onclick^=location]"` as path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of complicated dom parsing which would eventually fail on HTML errors of the parsed website I'd just use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

This is most likely faster and way less complicated

```
if ( preg_match_all( '/onclick="(location\\.href=([^"]+))"/i', $html, $matches ) )
{
    print_r( $matches );
}
```

[image]

Comment: Michel's solution worked great thanks for all your answers much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You're so close to success...

After several minutes of learning XPath on Wikipedia, I come up with this xpath that works:

```
$html=<<<TEXT
<html>
<body>
<div>
<div class="vad buttonDiv" onclick="location.href='http://example.htm?some/link&id=1357900324528'"></div>
<div class="vad buttonDiv" onclick="other('example')"></div>
<div class="vad buttonDiv" onclick="location.href='http://example.htm?some/link&id=7458758375733'"></div>
<div class="vad buttonDiv" onclick="other('example1')"></div>
<div class="vad buttonDiv" onclick="location.href='http://example.htm?some/link&id=3474537737392'"></div>
<div class="vad buttonDiv" onclick="other('example2')"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
TEXT;
```

```php
$dom=new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath=new DOMXPath($dom);
$divs=$xpath->evaluate("/html/body//div[starts-with(@onclick,'location')]");
foreach(range(0,$divs->length-1) as $i)
{
    var_dump($divs->item($i)->getAttribute("onclick"));
}
```

The above code outputs:

```
string(61) "location.href='http://example.htm?some/link&id=1357900324528'"
string(61) "location.href='http://example.htm?some/link&id=7458758375733'"
string(61) "location.href='http://example.htm?some/link&id=3474537737392'"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$url= "http://example.com";
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($url);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$PATH = $xpath->evaluate('/html/body//div[@class="vad buttonDiv"]');
for ($i = 0; $i < $PATH->length; $i++) {
    $lmao = $PATH->item($i);

$answer = $lmao->getAttribute('onclick');
$searchArray = array( "location.href='", "'");
$replaceArray = array( "", "");
$link = str_replace($searchArray, $replaceArray, $answer);
echo $link."<br>"
}
```

Display's just the link's.

Answer (score 1):

simple solution:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $onclicks->length; $i++) {
    $onclick = $onclicks->item($i);
    $display = $onclick->getAttribute("onclick");
    if(substr($display, 0, 8) == 'location'){
        $display = str_replace(array("location.href='", "'"), '', $display);
        echo $display."<br>";
    }

}
```